# Add header in awk script

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to add header to the output file and tried "print"/"printf" but still not successful to add header to the output file. Is there any other way to add header to the output file?

Here is the code I used:

```
begin {
    print "rtype cell# IMSI IMEI rcID scID SrID"
} 
{ 
  a1=substr($0,1,2)     ##  Record  type
  a2=substr($0,3,18)    ##  Cellular number
  a3=substr($0,21,15)   ##  IMSI number
  a4=substr($0,36,15)   ##  IMEI
  a5=substr($0,51,8)    ##  Receiving company ID
  a6=substr($0,59,8)    ##  Sending company ID
  a7=substr($0,67,8)    ##  Serving company ID
  a8=substr($0,75,8)    ##  Call placed  date
  a9=substr($0,83,6)    ##  Call placed  time
  b1=substr($0,89,6)    ##  Elapsed  time
  b2=substr($0,95,6)    ##  Chargeable  time
  b3=substr($0,101,6)   ##  Chargeable  units
  b4=substr($0,107,8)   ##  Rated  date
  b5=substr($0,115,21)  ##  Called number
  b6=substr($0,136,1)   ##  Call direction
  b7=substr($0,137,1)   ##  Completion indicator
  b8=substr($0,138,1)   ##  Termination Indicator
  b9=substr($0,139,8)   ##  Latitude
  c1=substr($0,147,8)   ##  Longitude
  c2=substr($0,155,1)   ##  Air time rate period
  c3=substr($0,156,11)  ##  Air time charges
  c4=substr($0,167,11)  ##  Surcharges
  c5=substr($0,178,1)   ##  Action code (1)
  c6=substr($0,179,2)   ##  Supp service code (1)
  c7=substr($0,181,1)   ##  Action code (2)
  c8=substr($0,182,2)   ##  Supp service code (2)
  c9=substr($0,184,1)   ##  Action code (3)
  d1=substr($0,185,2)   ##  Supp service code (3)
  d2=substr($0,187,1)   ##  Action code (4)
  d3=substr($0,188,2)   ##  Supp service code (4)
  d4=substr($0,190,1)   ##  Action code (5)
  d5=substr($0,191,2)   ##  Supp service code (5)
  d6=substr($0,193,15)  ##  Called place
  d7=substr($0,208,15)  ##  Calling place
  d8=substr($0,223,1)   ##  Zone indicator
  d9=substr($0,224,1)   ##  Toll rate period
  e1=substr($0,225,8)   ##  Toll call placed date
  e2=substr($0,233,6)   ##  Toll call placed time
  e3=substr($0,239,6)   ##  Toll call time
  e4=substr($0,245,11)  ##  Toll charges
  e5=substr($0,256,7)   ##  Distance
  e6=substr($0,263,3)   ##  Transaction Code
  e7=substr($0,266,5)   ##  Product Plan Code
  e8=substr($0,271,4)   ##  Bill Cycle
  e9=substr($0,275,11)  ##  Total Taxes
  f1=substr($0,286,11)  ##  Total Charges
  f2=substr($0,297,1)   ##  Call Type
  f3=substr($0,298,1)   ##  GSM Service Type
  f4=substr($0,299,2)   ##  GSM Service Code
  f5=substr($0,301,15)  ##  MSC ID
  f6=substr($0,316,2)   ##  Relaxed Rate Discount Flag
  f7=substr($0,318,1)   ##  Filler

  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|",a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9)
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|",b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9)
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|",c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9)
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|",d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9)
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|",e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9)
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7)
}
END {
}
```

Comment: I suspect `begin` must be capitalized: `BEGIN { ... }`. This is because I've never seen Awk code with a lower-case `begin`; perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yep, BEGIN and END should be capitalized.

Comment: @Kaz - You're right. It did not print header because of small cap. I tried the same code with "BEGIN" and it was all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kaz mentioned, you need `BEGIN` not `begin` but also if you're using GNU awk you don't need all those substr() calls and explicit printf statements when you can just specify the width of each field using FIELDWIDTHS, recompile the record using `|` between fields, and do one print. For example:

```
$ cat file
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
12345678901234567890

$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="2 3 2 4 2 5 2"; OFS="|"} {$1=$1} 1' file
ab|cde|fg|hijk|lm|nopqr|st
12|345|67|8901|23|45678|90
```

In your case you'd just do:

```
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="2 18 15 15 8 8 8 ..."
    OFS="|"
    print "rtype","cell#","IMSI","IMEI","rcID","scID","SrID"
} 
{ 
  $1=$1
  print
}
```

Note that specifying an empty END section is not useful

Comment: I really did not think of coming up with an effective solution like this. I'm new to awk; this will help me learning awk efficiently. Cheers!